# How to make floatThead work with DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

`floatThead` claims to work with `DataTables` out of the box. However, when I implement them the result isn't really satisfactory. I have a really wide and long table so I would like `DataTables` to be able to scroll horizontally, at the same time I would like it to have a floating thead when the user is scrolling down. The following code gives the table floating thead and it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $table = $('#price_summary');
        $table.DataTable();
        $table.floatThead({
            responsiveContainer: function($table){
                return $table.closest('.table-responsive');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But as soon as I add horizontal scroll to the table, floatThead seizes to take effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $table = $('#price_summary');
        $table.DataTable({
            "scrollX": true
        });
        $table.floatThead({
            responsiveContainer: function($table){
                return $table.closest('.table-responsive');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone know the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: Why not use the FixedHeaders plugin for dataTables, it does the same.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work even on their own website, am i missing something? https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/fixedHeader.html

Comment: I dont know why it is not working on that particular page, you can always find pages with broken examples or bad documentation, also for example on google API pages. Here is an example where it is working  -> https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/enable-disable.html  I am using FixedHeader a lot, have no problems at all.

Comment: This is from their official page: "Please note that FixedHeader is not currently compatible with tables that have the scrolling features of DataTables enabled (scrollX / scrollY). Please refer to the compatibility table for full compatibility details" https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/